# How to dismiss current view controller and parentviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift

I am presenting two view controller like so

```
self.presentViewController(choosePlace, animated: true, completion: nil)
self.presentViewController(shareController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and I want to dismiss both of them like this:

```
println("parent \(self.parentViewController)")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {

            self.parentViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            })
```

self.parentViewController is always nil though. How can I dismiss two at the same time?

Comment: have you tried just using `self.parentViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`? I would expect that to remove the presented viewController from the parent which in turn removes every view controller that was presented after that. Or is `parentViewController` already nil when you print it?

Comment: yeh the issue is parentViewController seems to be nil for some reason.. should I just assign the parent when I create that view controller?

Comment: now, that should be done automatically... I am not sure what happens if you present two viewcontrollers after one another - what happens to the view hierarchy

Comment: You are dismissing the view controller and then the variable gets deallocated. Create a pointer to it then dismiss the parent from that pointer.

Comment: @Scott Its still printing out nil though which is called before the first dismissviewcontroller

Comment: Oh. Try the .presentingViewController or .presentedViewController property. I can't remember which one off the top of my head but maybe that will have the same effect of what you want to do?

Answer (score 7):

You can:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { 
    self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
})
```

So, make sure that you are presenting your view controllers in order:

parentViewController -> choosePlace -> shareController

(arrows indicate "self.presentViewController")

Comment: doesn't work. Before the app can get a hold of the presenting view controller (the parent view controller), the reference is already nil

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4**

There where some issue I faced while trying Michael Voline's answer.

As the comment on the answer it did not work for me. it was because of the  `presentingViewController` was nil. 
So we need to set in a different property say `presentingController` but this will not work if you are setting it on the `viewDidLoad`

```
private var presentingController: UIViewController?
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    presentingController = presentingViewController
}
```

then

```
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
         self.presentingController?.dismiss(animated: false)
    })
```

I made the animation false so that the user will not see the UIof presenting view controller in the split seconds of dismissing.

Comment: After struggling for hours I found this and saved my day, thank you si much

Answer (score 3):

You can reference the presenting view controller during the function 'viewWillDisappear' of your view controller (i.e ShareController dismisses choosePlace just before it leaves scope).

```
//place the below in shareController 
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Does referencing the presentingViewController work within viewDidDisappear?

Comment: Also, if there's a special case where you don't want the code in viewDidDisappear or viewWillDisappear to execute, you can use an if statement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380208/skip-swift-viewcontroller-main-functions-such-as-viewdiddisappear/48380302

Answer (score 1):

If Michael Voline's solution doesn't work , try the following code.

```
let customViewController = self.presentingViewController as? CustomViewController

self.dismiss(animated: true) {

   customViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```