# Skip swift ViewController main functions such as viewDidDisappear

Tags: ios, swift, function, view

In my code, when a view disappears, a specific action occurs. I am doing it through the `viewDidDisappear()` function.
I have a specific button that when is pressed it goes to another view. I was wondering in what I way I could tell ONLY the function caused by a specific button to skip the `viewDidDisappear()`.

I perfectly know I can add a sort of 'if' statement in the `viewDidDisappear()` but I was wondering if there was a more efficient method.

Comment: You can't disable it... its related to controllers life cycle.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me.  What is it you *really* want to do?

Comment: I have an animation which moves all my subviews to the side, so that when the view appears again they can come in through an animation. Since the button I am talking about is a "secondary view" which is coming from the bottom, I would like the animation to not occur.

Comment: Just keep a bool and update its value when animation done   and keep a check on bool to start animation or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewDidDisappear()` is a `UIViewController`'s lifecycle callback method that's called by the environment - as far as I know there is no way to disable its calling. And I don't think there should be - as I mentioned, it is a part of `UIViewController`'s lifecycle, not calling it would break the contract - see its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller).

[image]

Therefore you have to (and you should) achieve what you want by using `if` statement.

Do something like this:

```
fileprivate var skipDisappearingAnimation = false

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    prepareInterfaceForDisappearing()
}

fileprivate func prepareInterfaceForDisappearing() {
    guard !skipDisappearingAnimation else {
        // reset each time
        skipDisappearingAnimation = false
        return
    }

    // do the stuff you normally need
}

@objc fileprivate func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    skipDisappearingAnimation = true
    // navigate forward
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done; you must handle the case manually with `if`, something like:

```
    var shouldSkip: Bool = false

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        if !shouldSkip {
            // your code goes here
        }
        shouldSkip = false // don't forget to set should skip to false again
    } 

    @IBAction func buttonDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
        shouldSkip = true // this will avoid run your code
        // your code here
    }
```